# How to do datable in flutter like this

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I need to hide and show in a data table like this below image
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>  Use this Code For the Hide and Show System
> ```

```
 Visibility(
  
      visible: false,
child : DataTable(
  columns: const <DataColumn>[
    DataColumn(
      label: Text(
        'Name',
      ),
    ),
    DataColumn(
      label: Text(
        'Age',
      ),
    ),
    ......
  ],
  rows: const <DataRow>[
    DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text('Mohit')),
        DataCell(Text('23')),
        DataCell(Text('Professional')),
      ],
    ),
    DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text('Aditya')),
        DataCell(Text('24')),
        DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
      ],
    ),
     ....
  ],
),
    ),
```

Then ---> onPressed(){
Visibility(

```
      visible: true,
```

}

Comment: i need to show below datacell

Comment: yes you can , just add the value right there thats it